# Regex C code is not working on my mac osx

Tags: c, regex, macos

I'm testing the following code on 4 Macbook. all Macbook are up to date with 10.8.4
on 3 of them it is working fine but not on my Macbook and I start be crazy.
I don't know what to do anymore.

```
include <regex.h>

...

regex_t re;
char msgbuf[256]
int reti;  
reti = regcomp( &re, ".*\\.xml", REG_EXTENDED | REG_NOSUB);
if( reti )
   printf("Could not compile regex : %d\n", reti);

reti = regexec (&re, "a.xml", 0, 0, 0) ;
if( !reti )
     puts("Match");
else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH )
     puts("No match");
else{
       regerror(reti, &re, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
       fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
    }
```

Here is the ouput:

```
Could not compile regex : 16
Regex match failed: invalid regular expression
```

I have perl 5.12 on all Macbook avec pcre 8.33
I even copy libpcre* from working macbook /usr/lib to my /usr/lib
it does not work

I reinstalled pcre

I try several expression, even simple one as ".*" and the answer is always : invalid regular expression and error code for regcomp : 16

Does anyone have any new ideas ?

Comment: Can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? Methinks you have UB somewhere in your code that's messing with ya.

Comment: I **reedit** the code to be more specific. 
Actualy, I'm trying to find .xml file with regex .*\.xml or ".*\\.xml"
this code is working fine on the 3 others Macbook. it finds the corresponding files

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions when you can be using `glob()`?

Comment: Thanks you for your answer but here it is just an exemple, on files and directories. Later this function could be use for URI/URL resolving as well as name resolving or text finding. I can't limit it at glob().

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think There is no errors in my code. The error was on a wrong link to regex.h. Once, I had coded for windows 7 and windows doesn't have /usr/include/regex.h directory (concept) so I installed the pcre package for windows in my current workspace with another regex.h file which was not compatible with my library pcre on my macbook. I cleaned my workspace and everything is back to normal.